# com.parse.ParseException: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new to parse ,i am able to store data to its database but whenever i try to retrieve some information like object-id from database i usually get the above mentioned error.Query which i am using to retrieve the object-id corresponding to the given Friend-id.

```html
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_Installation");
  query.whereEqualTo("FriendId", FrndTextString);
  
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
   public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
     
     for (ParseObject x : results) {
      String Objectid = x.getString("objectId");
      
      objectidEditText.setText(Objectid);
     }
    } else {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Error in retreving Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
       .show();
    }
   }
  });
```

Please help me in solving this issue as I googled a lot but haven’t found anything good solution.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The _Installation Class seems to be an internal class. Did you try use another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _Installation class is an internal class from Parse. The exception occurs because you are trying to access data that is protected by a specific user with specifc ParseACL .

Documentation from Parse:

> Every Parse application installed on a device registered for push notifications has an associated Installation object. The Installation object is where you store all the data needed to target push notifications. For example, in a baseball app, you could store the teams a user is interested in to send updates about their performance. Saving the Installation object is also required for tracking push-related app open events.
>
> In Android, Installation objects are available through the ParseInstallation class, a subclass of ParseObject. It uses the same API for storing and retrieving data. To access the current Installation object from your Android app, use the ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() method. The first time you save a ParseInstallation, Parse will add it to your Installation class and it will be available for targeting push notifications.

Try to use another Class, like "Ranking". Ex:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ranking");
query.whereEqualTo("FriendId", FrndTextString);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            
            for (ParseObject x : results) {
                String Objectid = x.getString("objectId");
                
                objectidEditText.setText(Objectid);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error in retreving Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
});
```

You have to pay attention to setup ParseACL correctly for each user and Class, if you want to find public information of others users. At least, all user have to be "Public Read" for data that you want.

Before saving any data in Parse, you have to setup the environment [with this tutorial](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new). After, you have to Create the ParseUser and login with it. Parse has an automatic way to create an user, just calling:

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().increment("RunCount");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

To save any data in Parse, you can use:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

Parse Server will automatically create the new class "GameScore", if is not exist. And will create all column, like "score", "playerNAme" and "cheatMode" if it not exist.

To go through with Parse, please [read API Doc](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide), it is so helpful.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply  ,but can you please tell me that how can i enter data in my new created class in parse. just an hint will be enough for me

Comment: Is this way we can put values in our new class :-
 ParseInstallation.create("sid").put("age",
     Integer.valueOf(ageTextString));

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only push to a query for Installations ....i am getting this error when send push notification..progrmattically

Comment: Hello Paulo,  here is the code on click of this I get the error mention above

Answer (score 2):

The Installation class can't be queried like that. Use ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation(); instead.

for example,

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getString("FriendId");